# How can I typecast a string to a structure which has char array members of different sizes?

Tags: c, string, struct

How can I typecast a string to a structure which has char array members of different sizes?
for example

```
typedef struct format{
    char test1[12];
    char test2[3];
    char test3[3];
    char test4[3];
    char test5[9];
    char test6[3];
    char test7[3];
    char test8[7];
    char test9[24];
    char test10[3];
    char test11[24];    
}format;
```

Now I will have one string which will be concated with above information & I simply want to parse the respective information from them and fill it to respective structure members.

Answer (score 2):

What's your rationale? You might be able to get away with:

**if C** :

```
// s is a null-terminated c string.
format* f = (format*)s;
```

that's all there is to it.

**if C++** :

```
// std::string s; // assuming basic_string<char>
// do stuff with s
format* f = reinterpret_cast<format*>(s.c_str());
```

Provided the string stays in scope. This might be risky depending on your STL implementation.

**For both C++ and C**: You also run the risk of reading past each string's extent if your string slices are not zero terminated and you call standard c-style string functions on the members of your format struct.

As undur_gongor and glglgl pointed out, this may not work if the alignment and padding of the char arrays inside the struct result in a non-tightly packed struct (i.e. there is extra padding as a result of alignment rules).

As Steve pointed out, On <s>most</s> all architectures a `char` is 1 byte, meaning you **should** be safe.

Comment: The question was about C. There is no such thing as `reinterpret_cast` or `c_str()`.

Comment: Why the downvote? When  I answered, there was no `C` tag. It is a trivial difference; I will update the answer. Looks like someone is on a downvote frenzy

Comment: @Preet: during the period when the question said C and your answer was for C++, it was reasonable for someone to downvote it. Downvote doesn't necessarily mean you did anything wrong, it means your answer wasn't a good answer to the question at time of voting. Unfortunately SO doesn't notify you when the question changes (invalidating your answer), or notify the downvoter when your answer changes (re-validating it).

Comment: @SteveJessop Exactly that. Plus, some people are not aware of C and C++ being completely different languages with different philosophies and approaches, invalidating the claim that "C++ is an improved C".

Comment: Beware that the `struct` might have gaps due to padding/alignment. In that case just casting will not work as intended.

Comment: @undur_gongor That was my thought as well, but with only `char[]` members, no padding should occur.

Comment: @glgl: "should" in the sense of "will probably" -- yes. But guaranteed by the C standard -- no. The C standard states "There may be unnamed padding within a structure object" with no restriction to any types.

Comment: Anyway, the simple pointer cast does what the questioner asks for, which is to treat the string as though it's laid out like the structure. Whether the structure actually has the correct layout for the data the questioner wants to read out of it is another matter ;-) Implementations usually provide non-portable ways to control padding, otherwise a lot of people's network code would be very difficult to port to that implementation. So you can use lots of asserts about `offsetof` to test if there's padding, and tell the structure to be packed if the asserts fail for some compiler.

Comment: "On most architectures a char is 1 byte" - on *all* implementations `sizeof(char)==1`, and the C standard chooses to call this unit of memory a "byte". Whether you call it a "byte" is a slightly different matter. But that's why internet RFCs and so on say "octet" instead when they mean 8 bits, to avoid contradicting any architecture's notion of a "byte" that's some other size.

Answer (score 0):

In C, there is nothing stopping you from casting this struct to a char* and treating it like a string.

Having said that however, you are going to have to be careful how you treat this "string". Consider the following example:

```
typedef struct format{
    char R[12];
    char M[15]; 
} format;

void main(){    
    format A;
    int i;

    strcpy(A.R,"AA");
    strcpy(A.M,"AABBCC");
    char *B=(char*)&A; //Note the typecasting
    printf("%s",B);     
    for (i=0;i<strlen(B);i++){
        printf("%d\n",*(B+i));
    }   
}
```

The example above is not going to work as expected, i.e. it is not going to iterate over all the characters within A because strings in C are null terminated (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string) and this is how various functions (strlen, strcpy and others) know that they have reached the end of a stream of chars. So, the above code will output "AA" and [65,65] (which is the asci equivalent of "A").

For the above piece of code to do what it is expected to do, we would have to EITHER:

1) Remove all "\0" (null) characters from A EXCEPT the last one, prior to treating it as a string (and feeding it to other functions like printf for example)

2) Or, if we want to maintain all individual fields as strings and still parse it, we would now have to use sizeof(format) (or sizeof(A)) instead of strlen(B) in the "for" iteration above.

So, yes you can typecast a struct of chars to a (char *) and treat it like a string but there's a bit of preprocessing you are going to have to do for this to work as expected. You could for example have a function that implements the removal of "\0"s as in (1) above, called something like "structToString".

Comment: Thank You very much for your reply. Now I have a string ready. But what should i do to parse the R and M  from them (as per above example) and fill it to respective structure members?